# How to force Entity Framework to map `internal` navigation properties?

Tags: c#, insert, entity-framework-5, cascade

Using `Code First` with `EF 5.0` I have the followings:

```
internal class Entities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

// User class which holds a list of 'Project' class
public class User
{
    private List<Project> _projects = new List<Project>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    internal List<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set { _projects = value; }
    }
}

// Project class which holds a list of 'Milestone' class
public class Project
{
    private List<Milestone> _milestones = new List<Milestone>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    internal List<Milestone> MileStones
    {
        get { return _milestones; }
        set { _milestones = value; }
    }
}
```

Although EF has created tables and relations correctly (one-to-many for: User=>Project=>Milestone) if I create a user with some projects and add it to `DbContext`, only the user will be added to and his projects won't. Same for a user with projects which have milestones. I'm doing it this way:

```
public void AddUser(User user)
{
    using (var repository = new Entities())
    {
        repository.Users.Add(user);
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My Question is how to force `EF` to INSERT or UPDATE complex entities automatically (cascading), hence adding a user with a list of projects, INSERTs the user in USERS table and his projects in PROJECTS table automatically (with correct relation)?

Is `EF` that smart in it's 5th version or I should do it manually?

Comment: Have you tried setting the setter to `private`?

Comment: @Justin: That doesn't work. I even made it `public IReadOnlyList` and `public IReadOnlyCollection` despite of my will but `EF` refuses to map readonly properties.

Comment: Can you make them public and alter the get/set to include your validation logic?

Comment: @Justin: As soon as I return the collection (list here) I have no access to modifications, unless I restrict modifications by making it a read-only collection.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how you don't have access to modifications?

Comment: @Justin: `IList` property which returns `MyList.AsReadOnly()` works but I even don't need my list to be accessible as readonly. I need `EF` to map it when it is private or internal. Answer to your question: Lists are Reference types, if return them (except as readonly collection), they can be modified directly.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Projects);
}
```

Comment: This gave you what you where looking for?

Comment: @Justin: Yes. This works fine without need to make `internal` to `public`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the desired result also by setting "protected internal" your "List Projects" and "List MileStones" properties. In this way EF can handle them. EF 'll override those properties using proxy class wrappers and you'll also have the lazy loading feature.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, EF is smart enough however it won't be able to add in your navigation properties when their access is set to `internal`. Make them `public` and your projects/milestones will be added.

```cs
// User class
public List<Project> Projects
{
    get { return _projects; }
    set { _projects = value; }
}

// Project class
public List<Milestone> MileStones
{
    get { return _milestones; }
    set { _milestones = value; }
}
```

Also, if you want to enable lazy loading on navigation properties you will also need to make them `public virtual` as EF internally has to make proxies for your model classes.

Comment: The reason they are `internal` is: I need to do some checks before allow adding/removing projects/milestones so hided the lists and provide two functions for that purpose (AddProject/RemoveProject), (AddMilestone/RemoveMilestone). Is there any way to signal `EF` do the work as they were `public`?

Comment: I don't think so, EF will need to access those to set/get your navigation properties when retrieving/updating database.

Comment: `EF` has access to them since code references `EF`. But I need to hide those list from direct changes and provide some methods for accessing them. Is there any `Data Annotation` to force `EF` consider them as `Public`? In fact I should make them `Private` but for some reason made them `Internal`.

Comment: As far as I know there are no data annotations to enable this. EF needs to be able to access those properties. Also having navigation properties set to private EF won't even be able to build a relationship (tested) unless you explicitly define the relationship.

Comment: If you really do not want to have these properties exposed to the client then consider using some sort of DTO on the client end where your data access populate your POCOs and then have a mapper to fill your DTOs and send them back to the client.

Comment: That way using `Code First` and `EF` loses it's advantage. I used it to code less not more. Anyway thanks for hints +1.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud The issue here is that in this case EF prevents proper encapsulations, which in my book is a serious offence to OO principles.