# Unable to save internal properties of a class into DB using EFCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been through the following - [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576288/how-to-force-entity-framework-to-map-internal-navigation-properties#16594593), it did not work for me and I am not using navigational properties.

`Entity`, lies in  - *Component.Shared.csproj* (which has everything public)

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

`User`, lies in - *Component.User.csproj* and inherits `Entity` class.

```
internal class User : Entity
{
    internal string FirstName { get; set; }
    internal string MiddleName { get; set; }
    internal string LastName { get; set; }
    internal string EmailId { get; set; }
    internal DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

`UserDbContext` lies in - *Component.User.csproj*.

```
internal sealed class UserDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UserDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //Remove pluralizing table name convention (Install package - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational)
        foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.SetTableName(entity.DisplayName());
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    internal DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

`UserRepository.cs` (*Component.User.csproj*).

```
internal class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    #region Private Fields
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkWithDbContext<UserDbContext, User> _uow;        
    #endregion Private Fields

    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWorkWithDbContext<UserDbContext, User> uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    bool IRepository<User>.Create(User user)
    {
        var userEntry = _uow.DbContext.Users.Add(user);
        return userEntry.IsAdded(); // IsAdded is an extension method - return EntityState.Added == entityEntry.State;
    }
}
```

**Question** - How do I force EF (for now, but it could be Dapper/Raw ADO.NET etc. in future) to save the values of internal properties of User or any class for that matter, without publicly exposing them, to avoid any direct changes from code outside of *Components.User.csproj*?

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=fluent-api%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) _"By convention, all public properties with a getter and a setter will be included in the model."_, you probably need to manually add all internal properties

Comment: (1) From OOP perspective, there is no difference between `internal` and `public` members of `internal` class.  Thus, just make them `public`. (2) EF entities represent the so called data model, hence should use minimal OOP sugars - basically class inheritance and virtual navigation properties, and that's it - no interfaces, no methods, no business logic, no private/protected/internal/unmapped members, simple public get/set properties.

Comment: 1/2 @IvanStoev I did this to create a boundary around `Component.User.csproj` members enforced by the compiler itself. So that they are not accessible by my fellow developers (un)intentionally, who are working on let's say `Components.Post.csproj` members. And in case they need something from `Componet.User` DB, then they access the APIs I have provided and not access the `IUserRepository` directly. I watched one of Simon's conference videos- [Modular Monoliths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OjqD-ow8GE) and I am trying to achieve it. [GitHub](https://github.com/phougatv/clean-architecture)

Comment: 2/2 @IvanStoev the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/phougatv/clean-architecture) is very basic and in early stage, feel free to browse it. In case you know a good post/blog to help me achieve this please share.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagree with these concepts (already shared my point) and not going to waste my time to support them. But even w/o all that, you don't seem to understand the (1) - there is **no** difference between `public` and `internal` properties of **internal** class. Other projects has no access to the class, thus the type of class properties doesn't matter. Inside the same project, all code has access to the class + its internal members, so these members are like public there. Internal members make sense only if the class is public.

Comment: I completely understood both of you're comments, I was just sharing the reason as to- _Why I did this?_

Answer (score 3):

You can set internal properties on saving entities in this way:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public AuditTrail(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        SetAuditInfo();
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        SetAuditInfo();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void SetAuditInfo()
    {
        var entries = context.ChangeTracker
            .Entries<Entity>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
            .ToList();

        var claim = _contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserId")?.Value;
        var userId = claim != null ? Guid.Parse(claim) : Guid.Empty;

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = userId;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = userId;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to prevent change you can create another object like `UserDto` that internal properties only have getter or remove them from DTO object.

Another option is setting the date on the database:

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
    .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;
```

You can also use [Shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .Property<DateTime>("CreatedOn");
}
```

And set value:

```cs
context.Entry(user).Property("CreatedOn").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
```